# C# 2D Animation - From slow to fast

Tags: c#, animation

Am not good in animation and I don't have a good formula to do some good animation.

I like to ask if you can share any codes that can move an object starting slowly then it gets faster? (accelerating)

I want to do something similar with Google's doodle today about "Eadweard Muybridge"

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try formulas like

```
Position.X = TimeSinceStart ^ 2
```

And try varying the exponent. (e.g. 1/2 or 1.5)